# "assuming x to decrease" vs. "assuming x decreases"

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Are both of the following sentences equally correct?

1. "Therefore we find x < y, assuming x decreases."
2. "Therefore we find x < y, assuming x to decrease."

I couldn't find any informations on whether the second form is correct too. It feels wrong to me but I can't justify why.

Thanks!

Comment: The first is more natural. The second is not ungrammatical; it just seems slightly awkward.

Comment: Both versions could be used, in their own appropriate circumstances.

Comment: There are apparently tens of thousands of written instances of [*assuming it to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22assuming+it+to%22), within which many/most are followed by a ***verb*** (which context matches OP's 2nd example). I see nothing wrong with the usage.

Answer (score -1):

the root of the word, assume, doesn't have a continuous principle,  actually assuming is  a conjunction,  can follow by a clause or noun, so the former choice is correct, the latter seems like "Ving + to do".